# mdadm /dev/md0 fails to load on boot

Tags: 14.04, raid, mdadm, mythbuntu

I am running mythbuntu 14.04 with a raid 6 setup using 10 hds.

Every time I boot my system, mdadm fails to load.  I have to run the following commands to get access to the system:

All commands run through sudo.

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md0
mdadm --assemble /dev/md0
mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sda
mount /home
```

Anyone have any suggestions on how to get this to load automatically upon boot?

The output from mdadm --detail /dev/md0

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Sun Jun 15 11:17:13 2014
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 31254835200 (29806.93 GiB 32004.95 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906854400 (3725.87 GiB 4000.62 GB)
   Raid Devices : 10
  Total Devices : 10
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Fri Jun 20 17:35:23 2014
          State : active, degraded, recovering
 Active Devices : 9
Working Devices : 10
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

 Rebuild Status : 0% complete

           Name : Muse:0  (local to host Muse)
           UUID : aa3fa2ce:2ba2ec23:39c1bcce:282788bf
         Events : 305197

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
      10       8        0        0      spare rebuilding   /dev/sda
       1       8       16        1      active sync   /dev/sdb
       2       8       32        2      active sync   /dev/sdc
       3       8       48        3      active sync   /dev/sdd
       4       8       64        4      active sync   /dev/sde
       5       8       80        5      active sync   /dev/sdf
       6       8      112        6      active sync   /dev/sdh
       7       8      128        7      active sync   /dev/sdi
       8       8      144        8      active sync   /dev/sdj
       9       8      160        9      active sync   /dev/sdk
```

The output from smartctl -l error /dev/sda

```
 smartctl -l error /dev/sda

 smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.13.0-29-generic] (local build)
 Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

 === START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
 SMART Error Log Version: 1
 No Errors Logged
```

Other notes:

```
mdadm --re-add /dev/md0 /dev/sda
```

results in:

```
mdadm: --re-add for /dev/sda to /dev/md0 is not possible
```

I have run

```
update-initramfs -u
```

My /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf looks like:

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR <spamfilter>

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=aa3fa2ce:2ba2ec23:39c1bcce:282788bf

# This file was auto-generated on Sat, 14 Jun 2014 14:24:44 +0200
# by mkconf $Id$
```